# Explicitely schedule innosetup to run next reboot?

Tags: inno-setup, schedule, reboot

I need to schedule **innosetup 5** to run next reboot in order to perform upgrade. My application EXE is supposed to run all the time in the system tray, the best way to run an update is to run it on reboot

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253897/how-do-i-schedule-an-install-to-happen-on-the-next-reboot-using-msi) but it's for MSI, and I'm not comfortable [touching user's registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6335840/1165880)

So, **is it possible to schedule innosetup to run on next reboot?** (ideally I need something that works on **Windows XP or later**)? If so, How?

Comment: The registry is the only way for run once entries. As your application already runs on startup, why not just set a flag so your application runs the setup on next startup then exits?

Comment: A better solution is to have the installer close and restart your application automatically, avoiding the reboot.  With Windows Vista/7 and the latest version of Inno you can get closing to happen automatically; some minor changes to your application or the installer are required to get it to start it again (see the [Restart Manager API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc948910.aspx) in MSDN).  For Windows XP or below you'll have to handling closing your app yourself.

Comment: @Miral Thanks but I'd like to avoid having to close my application (even for a brief time), for starter it's annoying to the user and second reboot is the best time to update without interfering with user's work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, but it requires setting a single registry value (as the [question you linked to said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6335840/588306)).

Creating a value in the `HKLM\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\RunOnce` key will cause the value to be run on next startup.

Alternatively, as your application already runs on startup, why not just set a flag so your application runs the setup on next startup then exits?

Comment: `why not just set a flag so your application runs the setup on next startup then exits?` Well I have a good reason: I didn't think about it! Seriously, thank you very much!

Comment: It's alright to use the registry since that's how many other systems does it (Like the Inno's "Product.iss")